# lockDays in Litepicker Js

Tags: javascript, json, date

Using Litepicker (https://github.com/wakirin/litepicker/) I'm having troubles adding lockDays to my calendar.
I'm retrieving some data from my DB and this is the JSON answer:

```json
{
    "error":0,
    "reservation_counter":1,
    "reservations":[
        {
            "start_date":"2022-02-28 00:00:00",
            "end_date":"2022-03-02 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I format the dates fields with this JS script

```js
const obj = JSON.parse(result);
if(parseInt(obj.error) === 0) {
    var lockedArray = [];
    if(parseInt(obj.reservation_counter) > 0){
        for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(obj.reservation_counter); i++) {
            let subArray = [obj.reservations[i].start_date.slice(0, 10), obj.reservations[i].end_date.slice(0, 10)];
            lockedArray.push(subArray);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this code is, as string: `[["2022-02-28", "2022-03-02"]]`, so is compliant with the Litepicker format.

To render the calendar, I use this script:

```js
$('input[name="litepicker"]').daterangepicker({
    parentEl: "#calendarelement-div",
    opens: 'center',
    inlineMode: false,
    minDate: new Date(),
    autoUpdateInput: true,
    singleMode: false,
    locale: {
        format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
        separator: " - "
     },
     lockDaysFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
     lockDays: lockedArray,
     disallowLockDaysInRange: true,
     highlightedDays: lockedArray
});
```

The calendar is fully working, but it not locks the dates. I tried with hand-coded dates, but nothing.
This is an image of the result:
[image: Calendar screenshot]

The expected resut is dates between 2022-02-28 and 2022-03-02 are locked, as JSON data.

I post the entire code to show the chronological order of the code

```js
$.ajax({
        url: 'php/getbedroomavailability.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { space: space, offer: offer, guests: guests},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            const obj = JSON.parse(result);
            if(parseInt(obj.error) === 0) {
                // No error
                var lockedArray = [];
                if(parseInt(obj.reservation_counter) > 0){
                    // Some reservations
                    for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(obj.reservation_counter); i++) {
                        let subArray = [obj.reservations[i].start_date.slice(0, 10), obj.reservations[i].end_date.slice(0, 10)];
                        lockedArray.push(subArray);
                    }
                }
                $('input[name="litepicker"]').daterangepicker({
                    parentEl: "#calendarelement-div",
                    opens: 'center',
                    inlineMode: false,
                    minDate: new Date(),
                    autoUpdateInput: true,
                    singleMode: false,
                    locale: {
                        format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
                        separator: " - "
                    },
                    lockDaysFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                    lockDays: lockedArray,
                    disallowLockDaysInRange: true,
                    highlightedDays: lockedArray
                });
                document.getElementById("ava-box").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("over-shadow").style.display = "block";
                simulateClick(document.getElementById("litepicker"));
                document.getElementById("selectfareckt").onclick = function () {
                    goCheckout(space, offer);
                }
            }
            else {
                alert(obj.error_msg);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: And those things happen in the right chronological order ...? You are done with filling `lockedArray`, before you call `$('input[name="litepicker"]').daterangepicker(...)` with it? _"I'm retrieving some data from my DB"_ - via an AJAX or fetch request, presumably? Did you handle the asynchronous nature of those correctly then?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added the entire code of the function. I think there are no problems with the async nature of the code.

Comment: In that code block I don't see you actually pushing anything to `lockedArray` now - you initialize it as an empty array, and that's it.

Comment: I forgot to paste that line of code, sorry. Fixed here

Comment: _"I tried with hand-coded dates, but nothing."_ - then we probably don't need to look for the reason in your AJAX code, if you did not get a "static" version working to begin with yet.

Comment: I also had the same idea. Bypassing the use of `lockedArray` and using for example the array `['2022-03-13']` the day is not disabled anyway. I looked at the repo and there are no similar cases in the issues, so I think it's a problem with my code.

Comment: _"Using Litepicker"_ - uhm, you sure about that? In the documentation, the only form of initialization I see, is `new Litepicker({...})`. You are using `$('input[name="litepicker"]').daterangepicker(...)`, which looks much more like a "standard" jQuery daterangepicker initialization. (And I did not see the documentation state anything like that the Litepicker was supposed to be a "drop in" replacement for a jQuery daterangepicker, so that it would use the same syntax and you only had to switch out the libraries, either.)

Comment: You're completely right! I forgot to change the initialization.
Thanks a lot